# Can I add a billing address while updating the cart?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, addresses

I'm designing a donation form right now for what will be a Craft Commerce site, and I want to collect the donator's billing name, address, etc in the product form which adds the donation to the cart. Will `commerce/cart/updateCart` accept `billingAddress` parameters when posted?

(I would simply test this, but I've not even started the build phase yet, and don't want to include the address fields on the donation form in my design if it won't be possible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can submit all updates to the cart in the one controller action `commerce/cart/update-cart`